# Howto have multiple Paint objects in IOS - swift as like in Androids Java

Tags: ios, swift

With Android and Java you have the ability to have multiple Paint objects.
Each Paint object has its own color or drawing thikness.

Is there a way to have this also in IOS swift ?

Example in Java for Android:

```
    paint1.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint1.setAlpha((int) (100.0 * fPercent));                                                    
    paint2.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    paint2.setAlpha((int) (200.0 * fPercent));

canvas.drawLine(x0, y0, x1, y1, paint1);
canvas.drawLine(x2, y2, x3, y3, paint2);
```